# Acronis recovery breaks shortcuts in Windows when restored on identical machine?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, hard-drive-recovery, acronis-trueimage

I'm using Acronis to create recover an disk image to a replacement system.
The image was created 2 weeks ago and is now being restored to a replacement machine(same batch, same vendor, same hardware)

I did this with the recovery mode restoring all partitions to the new machine. When the system is restored it logs in fine however all the shortcuts(desktop, startup, menu, taskbar) are broken and gives the error "the parameter is incorrect". When i go to the shortcut path everything works though.

Why is this happening and how can i solve for this in the future?